# Can only boot from Ubuntu USB and not from Windows USB

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb, grub

The laptop is a Sony Vaio E-series. Currently has Ubuntu installed on it with Grub, no Window's boot manager is visible.

I wish to switch back to Windows (completely, not dual boot) but I cannot boot from any USB drive that has Windows on it.

I tried a new Ubuntu ISO on the same USB drive and I am able to boot from it and even reinstall Ubuntu.

With Windows, I am getting the error `Operating system not found`. I tried enabling/disable secure boot but no luck.

Comment: Did you try to install with an DVD or USB stick? How did you burn the iso file? Is that a 32 or 64 bits PC? But the OS? Did you try the installation media on another computer?

Comment: USB, copied using Rufus. Tried two different Windows ISO's, both work fine on second laptop. Both ISO and laptop 64 bit.